# Get buttons to do something when they are checked

Tags: android

I got multiple buttons which are managed by this code:

```
ToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new ToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v, boolean isChecked) {
        int index;
        for(index = 0; index < viewIds.length; index++) {
            if (v.getId() == viewIds[index]) {
                getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit()
                        .putBoolean(stringIds[index], isChecked)
                        .apply();

                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

i've created method
   `scanButton();`
like this:

```
  private void scanButton() {

    Button scan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
    scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
            //here what will be done when button is clicked
            Log.d(TAG, "Button \"SCAN\" is pressed");
            Toast.makeText(RandDActivity.this, "Scan pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            //WHAT HERE

        }
    });


}
```

now Question: what to put here to get only those buttons which are isChecked with "true" state to do something?

Comment: Maintain Local Database

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to see whether the user has checked the button or not for that you can Load your SharedPreferences that you already saved in your onCheckedChanged() method, save it to a Boolean variable and then put a condition Like this:

```
if(isChecked){
//do your stuff with the button

}
```

I am assuming isChecked is your boolean variable that you just set with the value that you got from SharedPreferences.

Comment: yea but isChecked is local to listener... unless i am missing something.